# How to modify ajax src atributte without new request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I'm trying to make an iframe with a system that uses HTTP authentication. I'm using this code:

```
<iframe id="dashboard"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
                            $.ajax(
                                {
                                    url: \'https://mysystem.xxxx/\',
                                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                                    xhr.withCredentials = true;

                                    xhr.setRequestHeader(
                                    "Authorization", "Basic Z2Vxxxxxxxxxxx=="
                                    );
                                    },
                                     success: function(data) {
                                    $(\'#dashboard\').attr(\'src\', \'https://mysystem.xxxx\');
                                    $(\'#dashboard\').contents().find(\'html\').html(data);
                                    }

                                }
                            );
                        </script>
```

With this code, when the page is loaded, it generates three requests to the system:

- OPTIONS -> Validates CORS options; this is OK.
- GET -> Contains auth header. The system returns 200 and sends data.
- Other GET -> Without auth header. Then the system returns "401". This is a problem.

If I remove this line:

```
$(\'#dashboard\').attr(\'src\', \'https://mysystem.xxxx\');
```

The page loads, but static content of iframe (images, css, js) returns 404.

Comment: So, uhm... what does ajax have to do with this? the "Other GET" is completely unrelated to the ajax request. When you modify the src attribute of an iframe, it's gonna request what you told it to request. It's not going to have any headers you set in the ajax request because the two are completely unrelated.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your image, css, js assets with absolute paths, like: `https://somedomain.com/path/to/image.jpg`. In that way you will not need to provide the iframe an `src`.

**Update**

Assume that your server returns you `data` as a string, you can search & replace all the relative paths there to absolute one.

```js
const data = `<link rel="/css/relative/path" /><body><img src="/some/relative/path"/>
<img src="https://some-other-abs.com" /></body>`;

const absData = data.replace(/(?:rel|src)="([^"]+)"/g, function(group, match) {
  if (!match.startsWith('http')) {
    return group.replace(match, `http://example.com${match}`);
  }
  return group;
})
console.log(absData);
```

Comment: The iframe content is generated by the system, is not possible modify to absolute paths.

Comment: You can always do that ajax, get the `data` as string, and apply some string replaces to add that absolute paths.

Comment: How to do this? Can give-me a example (sorry, I'm learning ajax)?

Comment: Added a snippet